# Joining three tables in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to join three tables in Snowflake, but getting an error on a third one, and not sure if I used a good key :

```sql
select
  a.CALENDAR_DATE
  , a.SALES_DOCUMENT
  , a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER
  , *bAUBEL
  , *b.NETWR_ship*
  , a.Delivery_time
  , a.Route_label
  , ue.order_ID
from DWHM_MALLGROUP.DM_LOG.SHIPMENTS a
left join (
  select
    AUBEL,
    sum(NETWR) as NETWR_ship
  from DWHM_MALLGROUP.SRC_SAP_ERP."2LIS_13_VDITM"
  where MATNR in ('10027', '10200', '10402', '10500', '10602', '10603', '10650', '10700')
  group by AUBEL
) b
  on a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER = b.AUBEL
where
  a.CALENDAR_DATE >= '2020-04-01'
  and a.ROUTE in ('CZSK12', 'CZSK21', 'CZSK22', 'CZSK23', 'CZSK24', 'CZSK25', 'CZSK26', 'CZSK27', 'CZSK28', 'CZSK29', 'CZSK30', 'CZSK32', 'CZSK33', 'CZSK34', 'CZSK51', 'CZSK53', 'CZSK54', 'CZSK56')
group by a.CALENDAR_DATE, a.SALES_DOCUMENT, a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER, b.AUBEL, b.NETWR_ship, a.delivery_time, a.Route_LABEL
left join "DWHM_MALLGROUP"."DM_COMMERCIAL"."UNIT_ECONOMICS" as ue
  ON a.SALES_DOCUMENT = ue.order_id
  where ue.country = 'SI'  and ue.delivery_date >= '2019-08-01'
```

Comment: What's your error?

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd LEFT JOIN should be moved up to before the WHERE clause:

```
select
  a.CALENDAR_DATE
  , a.SALES_DOCUMENT
  , a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER
  , b.AUBEL
  , b.NETWR_ship
  , a.Delivery_time
  , a.Route_label
  , ue.order_ID
from DWHM_MALLGROUP.DM_LOG.SHIPMENTS a
left join (
  select
    AUBEL,
    sum(NETWR) as NETWR_ship
  from DWHM_MALLGROUP.SRC_SAP_ERP."2LIS_13_VDITM"
  where MATNR in ('10027', '10200', '10402', '10500', '10602', '10603', '10650', '10700')
  group by AUBEL
) b
  on a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER = b.AUBEL
left join "DWHM_MALLGROUP"."DM_COMMERCIAL"."UNIT_ECONOMICS" as ue
  ON a.SALES_DOCUMENT = ue.order_id
where
  a.CALENDAR_DATE >= '2020-04-01'
  and a.ROUTE in ('CZSK12', 'CZSK21', 'CZSK22', 'CZSK23', 'CZSK24', 'CZSK25', 'CZSK26', 'CZSK27', 'CZSK28', 'CZSK29', 'CZSK30', 'CZSK32', 'CZSK33', 'CZSK34', 'CZSK51', 'CZSK53', 'CZSK54', 'CZSK56')
and ue.country = 'SI'  and ue.delivery_date >= '2019-08-01'
group by a.CALENDAR_DATE, a.SALES_DOCUMENT, a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER, b.AUBEL, b.NETWR_ship, a.delivery_time, a.Route_LABEL
```

NOTE: I am not familiar with the `*b` that you have in the SELECT clause... it looks like another typo to me, so I removed it.

If you are trying to perform the aggregate (GROUP BY) before the 2nd LEFT JOIN, then you can use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (
select
  a.CALENDAR_DATE
  , a.SALES_DOCUMENT
  , a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER
  , b.AUBEL
  , b.NETWR_ship
  , a.Delivery_time
  , a.Route_label
from DWHM_MALLGROUP.DM_LOG.SHIPMENTS a
left join (
  select
    AUBEL,
    sum(NETWR) as NETWR_ship
  from DWHM_MALLGROUP.SRC_SAP_ERP."2LIS_13_VDITM"
  where MATNR in ('10027', '10200', '10402', '10500', '10602', '10603', '10650', '10700')
  group by AUBEL
) b
  on a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER = b.AUBEL
where
  a.CALENDAR_DATE >= '2020-04-01'
  and a.ROUTE in ('CZSK12', 'CZSK21', 'CZSK22', 'CZSK23', 'CZSK24', 'CZSK25', 'CZSK26', 'CZSK27', 'CZSK28', 'CZSK29', 'CZSK30', 'CZSK32', 'CZSK33', 'CZSK34', 'CZSK51', 'CZSK53', 'CZSK54', 'CZSK56')
group by a.CALENDAR_DATE, a.SALES_DOCUMENT, a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER, b.AUBEL, b.NETWR_ship, a.delivery_time, a.Route_LABEL
) c1
select
  c1.CALENDAR_DATE
  , c1.SALES_DOCUMENT
  , c1.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER
  , c1.AUBEL
  , c1.NETWR_ship
  , c1.Delivery_time
  , c1.Route_label
  , ue.order_ID
left join "DWHM_MALLGROUP"."DM_COMMERCIAL"."UNIT_ECONOMICS" as ue
  ON c1.SALES_DOCUMENT = ue.order_id
and ue.country = 'SI'  and ue.delivery_date >= '2019-08-01'
```

This can (and should, IMO) be cleaned up some more, but I am trying to address the question you asked about joining 3 tables.

Comment: the error is this one :[SQL compilation error: error line 9 at position 4 'UE.ORDER_ID' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.]

Comment: You got that error on your original SQL, but what about the code I provided you here?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the SQL.

```
, *bAUBEL
  , *b.NETWR_ship*
```

we only use `*` for selecting all fields from a table. For example `select A.* , B.col1  from Table_a A , Table_B`

sequence for join is

1. SELECT
2. FROM Table
3. JOIN other Table
4. JOIN Condition
5. WHERE
6. GROUP BY
7. HAVING

Try this SQL

```
SELECT
    a.calendar_date,
    a.sales_document,
    a.document_number_cross_border,
    b.aubel,
    b.netwr_ship,
    a.delivery_time,
    a.route_label,
    ue.order_id
FROM
    dwhm_mallgroup.dm_log.SHIPMENTS a
left join (
  select
    AUBEL,
    sum(NETWR) as NETWR_ship
  from DWHM_MALLGROUP.SRC_SAP_ERP."2LIS_13_VDITM"
  where MATNR in ('10027', '10200', '10402', '10500', '10602', '10603', '10650', '10700')
  group by AUBEL
) b
  on a.DOCUMENT_NUMBER_CROSS_BORDER = b.AUBEL
  left join "DWHM_MALLGROUP"."DM_COMMERCIAL"."UNIT_ECONOMICS" as ue ON a.sales_document = ue.order_id
WHERE
    a.calendar_date >= '2020-04-01'
    AND a.route IN (
        'CZSK12',
        'CZSK21',
        'CZSK22',
        'CZSK23',
        'CZSK24',
        'CZSK25',
        'CZSK26',
        'CZSK27',
        'CZSK28',
        'CZSK29',
        'CZSK30',
        'CZSK32',
        'CZSK33',
        'CZSK34',
        'CZSK51',
        'CZSK53',
        'CZSK54',
        'CZSK56'
    )
        AND ue.country = 'SI'
            AND ue.delivery_date >= '2019-08-01'
GROUP BY
    a.calendar_date,
    a.sales_document,
    a.document_number_cross_border,
    b.aubel,
    b.netwr_ship,
    a.delivery_time,
    a.route_label
  ue.order_id
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried, but still got ['UE.ORDER_ID' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.] so i guess it will be something with that identifier

Comment: add `  ue.order_id`  at end.  I have updated my answer

Comment: yes yes I have tried, thank you very much, but there is still error on UE identifier